# can we automate consolidated userprofiles in salesforce by selenium with java? how?

Tags: opportunity

can we automate the consolidated user profiles by using selenium? im new to sales force...what are the possibilities?

As im new to sales force i don't have that much clarity on this

Comment: Consider that profiles contain a very large number of elements and that (AFAIK) no-one has yet created a great tool for managing them so this is likely to be a big job unless your aims are quite limited.

Answer (score 1):

In *theory*, you could, but this would be incredibly "messy" to get just right. Consider using the [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/) instead. Using this API will get you the files that you can parse out (it's plain XML), and merge them together however you like. Using Selenium would require a lot of experimentation to get right.